# Show or hide banner

Tags: wordpress

Hiding banner on mobile view and show it on the desktop view without using bootstrap.

```
<img src="https://www.toko.lk/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/meta@toko2.lk_.jpg" 
alt="Online Shopping Sri Lanka" class="resetImage" style="max-height:100%;width:480px" />
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow, please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533942/hiding-an-image-in-responsive